# Catch an error while importing huge CSV in queue using laravel excel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-excel

I am using `ShouldQueue` method to have the large CSV into Queue but the errors of validations I am not able to catch them!

```
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        ImportFailed::class => function(ImportFailed $event) {
            dd($event); // This I will write into the FILE or send EMAIL but the job runs successfully but validation errors keep empty.
            $this->importedBy->notify(new ImportHasFailedNotification);
        },
    ];
}
```

My code looks like below

```
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ImportFailed::class => function(ImportFailed $event) {
            $filename = public_path('tmp').'/validation_error.txt';
            $myfile = fopen($filename, "w");
            fwrite($myfile, "domo");
            fclose($myfile);
            },
        ];
    }
```

I am in hope that if there is any error validation_error.txt file will have "Demo" inside it.

Also, I have crossed verify by removing `ShouldQueue` it gives me proper errors for email already exists a kind of.

Please help if you have any ideas! Thanks!

Comment: Still no luck @anyone has face the same issue??

Comment: How did you fix this @shashank

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: @Vishal Have removed this extension and done code manually. I have created a chunk of 500 records ( array ) and push into the queue also  I made one file which appends whatever errors we fetch and once all job completed I send an email to my admin user